# Javascript strange behavior with for loop and ejs variable

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am currently stuck regarding this code for about 3 hours now. I'm sure I am making a very silly mistake and hopefully somebody can help me point this out.

Basicially I cannot do this

```
var id = '<%=data[i]._userDetail._id%>';
```

But I can do this

```
var id = '<%=data[1]._userDetail._id%>';
```

Why can't I use "i" as variable here? I have tested this and it is not an out of bound issue. Every time I use "i" it will tell me that the variable is undefined "_userDetail" etc.

```
<script>

        for (var i = 0; i < '<%=data.length%>'; i++) {
            if(document.getElementById("select_user").options[i].value === '<%=requestUserID%>' ){

                document.getElementById("select_user").selectedIndex = i;
            }

            var id = '<%=data[1]._userDetail._id%>';
            var nickname = '<%=data[1].nickname%>';
            var phone = '<%=data[1].phone%>';
            var lineID = '<%=data[1].lineID%>';


                document.getElementById("requestUserID").value = id;
                document.getElementById("nickname").value = nickname;
                document.getElementById("phone").value = phone;
                document.getElementById("lineID").value = lineID;


        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It should be `var id = '<%=data[' + i + ']._userDetail._id%>'; ` Since `i` is a variable hence you can append it into string formation for id.

Comment: Hello it is still throwing an error

84| >> 85| var id = '<%=data[' + i + ']._userDetail._id%>'; 86| var nickname = '<%=data[' + i + '].nickname%>'; 87| var phone = '<%=data[' + i + '].phone%>'; 88| var lineID = '<%=data[' + i + '].lineID%>'; Cannot read property '_userDetail' of undefined

Comment: The templates are processed on the server, the surrounding JavaScript runs on the client. Two completely different environments.

Comment: So how would I go on about this? It is totally fine if I use the ejs in html but it looks abit messy

Comment: Why are you using ejs at all here?

Comment: I rendered a view from node.js with data as a varaible passed in here.